# complex calculations in php or ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Is it possible to do complex formula calculations in php or ajax?

Specifically, calculating the root 12 of a number or elevate the nth degree?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? What have you looked up? (-1)

Comment: ajax would be Javascript right ? and what @pst said.

Comment: I have to use a formula for the calculation of bank loans. I´m completely lost, because I don´t know how implement it

Comment: I have to use data from a database and others that the user enter via form. but the main question is, how should I implement the root 12 of a number?

Comment: @user1708892 For future reference, don't ask "is X possible", but ask "how can I do X": e.g. "How can I compute the nth root of a number in PHP?". To get a better response, show what has already been done or looked at: e.g. "None of the standard math functions work with arbitrary roots" or "Pow only works with integer exponents", etc.

Answer (score 2):

try php [GMP Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php). These functions allow you to work with arbitrary-length integers.

Comment: nice, didn't know those functions.

Comment: not sure if you are actually didnt know about GMP or you are trolling me. :-D

Comment: i hand coded arbitrary length number calc functions. so i really killed myself!